# Generate pdf from php(have to retrieve from mysql database)

Tags: php, database, pdf

I have already created a report using list of data from my database. i have a button in that page "Click to generate Pdf". if i click that button the same report have to come as pdf report. now i need to convert that reports as PDF. i have googled past some days but i couldn't find the answers. all are saying and giving values directly into tables and they were generated it. But I need retrieve it directly from my database. i wanna to get it directly from queries....

If any one know means kindly give your answers. hope you guys got my ques..

Thanks in Advance.

Update : here is my script pdf.php

```
<?php
include ('connection.php');
require('fpdf.php');

$joined = $_GET['joined'];
list($ZoneNo, $InstituteNo, $Year) = split('[,]', $joined);
//echo "ZoneNo: $ZoneNo; Institute: $InstituteNo; Year: $Year<br />\n";

$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);

$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(20,15,"No");
$pdf->Cell(50,15,"Institute Name");
$pdf->Cell(50,15,"Course Name");
$pdf->Cell(50,15,"No. Of Students");
$pdf->Cell(50,15,"Year");
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(450,3,"--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");


        $sql = "SELECT im.InstituteName,cm.CourseName,COUNT(sm.CourseNo),sm.Year FROM student_master sm,course_master cm,institute_master im WHERE ((sm.Year='".$Year."') AND (sm.InstituteNo='".$InstituteNo."') AND (sm.ZoneNo = '".$ZoneNo."')) AND (im.InstituteNo = sm.InstituteNo) AND (cm.CourseNo = sm.CourseNo) GROUP BY sm.CourseNo ORDER BY im.InstituteName,cm.CourseName";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        $No = 0;
        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $No = $No + 1;
            $InstituteName = $rows[0];
            $CourseName = $rows[1];
            $Total = $rows[2];
            $Year = $rows[3];
            $pdf->Cell(20,15,"{$No}");
            $pdf->Cell(50,15,"{$InstituteName}");
            $pdf->Cell(50,15,"{$CourseName}");
            $pdf->Cell(50,15,"{$Total}");
            $pdf->Cell(50,15,"{$Year}");    
        }

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

note you guys here am getting only the output as

### No  InstituteName   Course name    No. of students    Year

can you explain it now guys????

Guys Check this link http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/30/ if you have problems

Comment: Uhh, what? What product is this? Is this something you're writing?

Comment: You can't get data from a database without querying it.

Comment: ya alex, i have qureried it , and i couldn't get the answer.

Comment: hi chris, i'm creating a report in my project...

Comment: i have to thank all, who has given the downvote for this question..lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try FPDF liberary as mentioned by diEcho above. You can find the Tutorials on their website. Here's a complete example of exporting data from mysql using the FPDF:

http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/30/

Also here:
http://www.weberdev.com/get_example-3720.html

Hope it helps

Comment: I have tried the same which you gave in this link http://www.fpdf.de/downloads/addons/30/  ... am getting tha same result what i have given in my question...thank u for your try..

Comment: @Sriram90 may be theres some error in your query. try fetching the data using your query in plain php file, so that you know if theres error in query or in the class.

Comment: Hurrah !!! i got the answer....i have done a mistake in query and passing datas...thank you once again for notify my mistake....

Answer (score 0):

You should create PDF template (with HTML) and then query the database. Without template you can't organize the data. 
You can use [mPDF](http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/) library (my favorite).

Answer (score 0):

You could also try [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/)

Answer (score 0):

### PDF Report Writing

Step 1. Query your database

Step 2. Format a HTML Report

Step 3. WKhtmltopdf the report into a pdf, serve for download

WKhtmltopdf will take a html page, use web kit to render it and output it as a PDF file

See here: http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/